# Trace Javascript event handling in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Is there a browser that will allow me to trace the execution of Javascript events? For example, for some random site online, if I click on something in one area of the page, it causes the text in some other area of the page to get updated with some new text. I would like to be able to trace what happens from the click all the way to the value being updated. When I say trace I mean that I would like the browser to tell me the name of the Javascript function that handles the click (and which file it is located in) and which Javascript function updates the value on the page.

The solution must work for any random website on the internet.

Comment: use the developer tool with the build-in javascript debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome you can trace js codes in website with DEBUG mode.

1. Open Chrome.
2. Open a website.
3. Open Dev Tool with press **F12**. [image]
4. On the menu click **Sources**. Now you can see all js files at there. And there is a debug panel. You can start, renew, break, trace a code line with these tools.
5. On js code panel you can put breakpoints on the line numbers.
   [image]
6. Press **F5** and refresh the page. Code will pause and you can trace js values.